# mkdirp.sync is not a function ? Persists after deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling all dependencies

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run a node.js script to visit a website scrape the list of street names and then create an HTML page for each one.

However I'm getting the error message:

```
"TypeError: mkdirp.sync is not a function
    at createDirectory (/Users/name/Documents/WebDev/street-owl/page-generator.js:15:12)
    at Element.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Documents/WebDev/street-owl/page-generator.js:65:5)"
```

The top of my script includes: `const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');` and I've installed mkdirp. Seems to be getting stuck here:

```
// Helper function to create a directory if it doesn't exist
function createDirectory(dirPath) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
    mkdirp.sync(dirPath);
  }
}
```

Comment: `const { mkdirp } = require( "mkdirp")`.

Comment: Thanks, I've already got that added see above.

Comment: Yes but you are doing it incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing `sync` incorrectly based on your require statement. The library has a default export that contains a `mkdirp` object with the `sync` method.

Try this

```
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp").mkdirp

// or

const {mkdirp} = require("mkdirp")
```

See the [reference example](https://github.com/isaacs/node-mkdirp#example).